# RuntimeException when updating from command line

Tags: 9, composer

I went to my website's directory and ran:

```
composer update
```

> [RuntimeException]
> Could not delete /home/example/public_html/example.com/web/sites/default/default.services.yml:

`ls -la` output:

> `-rw-rw-r--  1 example example  7732 Aug 28 03:52 default.services.yml`

Should I take any action, if so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the core 9.4.7 update, the `default.services.yml` file was updated.  However, if your permissions are set correctly on the `/default` directory and the `default.services.yml` file, then composer update will fail with the "could not delete" permissions warning.

You can solve this as follows on most versions of linux and macOS.

First, delete `default.services.yml`. (You may need to use `sudo` (`sudo rm default.services.yml`).

Next, try running `composer install` (since you have already run the update, running `install` will cause the scaffolding to be reset).  If the file is created properly, [check the permissions against this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16994) and if they are ok, you are done.

If the file cannot be created, carefully change the permissions of the `default` directory (but not any child/subdirectories) to `777` (`chmod default 777`), run `composer install` again to create the file, and then change the permissions for the `default` directory back to 755 (`chmod default 755`).

### Why does this happen?

Drupal needs file permissions for services files to be set securely so that they cannot be changed by just anyone.  Unfortunately, this makes updating these files a bit of a pain because the update requires manual intervention (since the files can't be easily overwritten automatically, unlike most Drupal files in updates).

Comment: I got `Nothing to install, update or remove`.

Comment: I have already deleted the sites/default/default.services.yml file, how could I reverse this?

Comment: sites/default/default.services.yml was somehow re-created, well no in composer update I get `Nothing to install, update or remove`.

Comment: Usually after composer performs the update/install of modules, then the scaffolding files, which includes `default.services.yml`, will be checked and generated if they do not exist.

Comment: @markus Have you fixed the problem?  I'm unable to tell by your third comment whether you were able to solve the problem or not.

Comment: Yes, my version is now 9.4.7 seems I got after this in peace.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue when upgrading Drupal 9.4.8 to 9.5.0 and this link helped me, I believe it will help you too :)

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/290297/35202