# RuntimeException Could not delete /path/web/sites/default/default.services.yml:

Tags: 9

I have installed Drupal 9 with Composer.

I didn't install any modules, themes or customize anything. It's a plain Drupal installation.

After a few months I did `composer update` in that website's directory and the process seems to went well besides:

```
[RuntimeException] Could not delete /path/web/sites/default/default.services.yml:
```

The website itself is working after this procedure (tested from a browser with cleared cache).

Should I ignore this warning/error? I mean, shouldn't this file stay the same anyway?

Comment: This solution works nicely for this error https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/290297/35202

Answer (score 0):

The file `default.services.yml` is part of the Drupal scaffold and can change on a composer update. You shouldn't edit the file, remove it or change the file permissions. If you need to change the defaults, copy the file content to `services.yml` and change it there.

Comment: I don't think I need to change the defaults. Do I?

Comment: No, unlike settings.php. which any site has to change at least for the database credentials (with the help of the installer), the services parameters need to be changed only in specific cases. For example the session cookie life time or Twig debugging.